# Dynamic Linking when Migrating C++ Program from Solaris to Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, solaris, c, glibc

### The Problem

I'm attempting to migrate a legacy application's build process from an older Solaris machine to Linux, specifically, RHEL 7.7. The application was originally built using Solaris Studio (now known as Oracle Developer Studio). After installing as many dependencies as I could find and tweaking the compilation flags, I was able to get the code to compile into the various executables.

When I try to run one of them from the command-line, I get the following:

```
$ ./myexecutable
bash: /path/to/my/myexecutable: /usr/lib/amd64/ld.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

### My Attempts

It seems that it's looking for the old dynamic linker, which supports linking archive files (also known as `.a` files). Using `ld-linux.so.2` via a symbolic link yields an error message that says that the library is corrupted.

```
$ ./myexecutable
bash: /path/to/my/myexecutable: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

I also found `/usr/share/man/man8/ld.so.8.gz`. I decompressed it and created a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/amd64/ld.so.1` but that yielded the same error as above.

Using `yum whatprovides` I couldn't find any packages that supply `ld.so.1`. The only other thing I can think to do is track down the source for the `glibc` version of `ld.so.1` and try to compile that.

Please let me know if you know how to get `ld.so.1` on RHEL 7.x (AMD64) or some kind of workaround that would allow me to run my program without the use of that shared library.

Comment: `/usr/lib/amd64/ld.so.1` is the right path for Solaris, but the linker should automatically fill in the correct value for you. Are you sure you haven't cross-compiled a binary for Solaris instead of natively compiling a Linux binary? What does your link command look like?

Comment: If your compilation process is actually creating a new `myexecutable` file, you've probably missed a shared object in your dependencies and are still picking up one in your build tree that was built for Solaris.    What's the result from `file myexecutable` and `ldd myexecutable` on your Linux system after you've built a new Linux copy of `myexecutable`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I get the following `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped, uses FPU FXSR SSE` using `file` and `not a dynamic executable` using `ldd`.